# SSLHanshakeException while establishing communication from Springboot service to 3rd part api using p12 keystore

Tags: java, certificate, spring-cloud-feign, p12

From our Springboot application we need to connect to a 3rd party service. And we have the p12 certificate provided by the third party vendor.

I was successfully establish communication with this service via browser and postman client just by importing the p12 certificate as pfx file.

Now I am trying to import or use this P12 certificate in my service to communicate.
But keep getting the following error.

```
feign.RetryableException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Methods that I tried:

1. using open ssl commands extracted the certificates and imported jks truststore from p12 file in one of my folders using keytool

```
   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12  
   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\thirdparty.p12 
   -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=<pwd> 
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks 
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\\thirdparty.jks 
   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<pwd>
```

2. created a custom feignconfiguration as specified
   https://dzone.com/articles/ssl-based-feignclient-example-in-java-microcervice
3. Just imported p12 certificate in dockerfile and tried running the docker

```
   RUN cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin && keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit - 
   destkeypass changeit -destkeystore cacerts -deststoretype pkcs12 -srckeystore  thirdparty.p12 - 
   srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass <pwd>
```

everything gives the same error.

I think I am missing something that could be very simple too.
Questions:

1. When I have p12 file from the vendor, do I need a separate truststore created for this?
2. Is there way I can just use the p12 and the password to establish the communication ?
3. Do I need to do the configuration in service level or in feign client level?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: You can refer : https://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed/

Answer (score 1):

1. Open URL in your browser and export certificate.
2. Find location of **cacerts** files :

   Example : C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts.
3. Import the .cer file into cacerts in command line:

   `keytool -import -alias example -keystore  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.6.0_22\lib\security\cacerts -file example.cer`

Note : If asked for password enter : **changeit**

Restart your JVM/PC.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your input Amit Kumar.

Yes it works by importing the certificates in Truststore and providing the keystore as I mentioned in my question.

But the Springboot JPA Hikari is automatically trying to verify the Trustcertificates that I provided in java command line and hence the server was not coming up.

Trying to resolve that problem now.